# SSRS: position of a chart

Tags: reporting-services

How can I fix the chart in SSRS?
I have got 2 charts in my report and when I add a tablix under the chart the second chart move

Answer (score 0, accepted):

embed both the charts in a rectangle, and leave the tablix outside the rectangle